# await does not work as expected inside a loop when the code is executed by puppeteer - but it works perfectly when run in browser's console

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I am evaluating `codeToBeEvaluated` function in browser using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). `codeToBeEvaluated` has a `while` loop which is supposed to show an `alert` (see LINE B) after every 10s.

**The problem is when I run this script, I don't see any alerts. Code execution doesn't wait for 10s in Line A. Rather process exits immediately.** I have no idea why. I am really curious why it's not working.

Interestingly, when I run only the `codeToBeEvaluated` function in the browser's console, it works perfectly fine and I see the alerts that I am supposed to see.

It would be awesome if someone could explain this behaviour. I am not looking for any workarounds to show up alerts. I just want to understand this behaviour.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


// this function will be executed in the browser
// it should create an alert after some time interval
const codeToBeEvaluated = async () => {
  let index_2 = 0;

  // a promise that resolves after ms*1000 seconds
  async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }

  // await within function's while loop
  async function whileWrapper() {
    while (index_2 < 10) {
      await sleep(10000); // LINE A: execution doesn't stop at all :/
      alert("hello " + index_2); // LINE B: does NOT execute at all
      index_2++;
    }
  }

  whileWrapper();
};

async function main(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    // args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url);

  await page.evaluate(codeToBeEvaluated);

  browser.close();
}

main("https://www.google.com/search?q=hello");
```

Comment: Puppeteer seems to ignore alerts by default; this makes perfect sense, given that it's supposed to be used for automation. Here's the first google result for "puppeteer alert": https://chercher.tech/puppeteer/alerts-puppeteer#alerts-dialogs-puppeteer

Comment: Not when launch({ devtools: true }), which i am using in above script. If I put alert in anywhere out of whileWrapper it shows up fine. both alert and debugger work perfectly fine for devtools: true

Comment: @ChrisG its really not a problem related to alerts. the problem really is that code after line A isnt executed at all. Even if I put await sleep(10000) puppeteer terminates without waiting for 10000*10 to finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason for the difference between executing `codeToBeEvaluated` on DevTools manually vs. from your puppeteer script is that:

- on DevTools console the script has infinite time to execute a longer async command (except if you are quickly closing the browser while it is still running)
- in your puppeteer script you have other commands following the `page.evaluate` like `browser.close` (which I advise you to put after an `await` as it returns a promise!), so the browser is closed before the function would finish

you need to await `whileWrapper()`'s promise too, so changing your code in LINE 25 to the following will make it behave as you would have expected:

```js
  await whileWrapper();
```